# Bidirectional mapping and saving multiple entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have two tables `Student` and `Address` table. I want bidirectional mapping between them. The second thing that I want is address gets automatically added from the student entity when the address is in the student class.

Bidirectional mapping is achieved by this code:

```java
@Entity
class Student {

    @Id
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "student")
    private Address address;
}

@Entity
class Address {

    @Id
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
    private Student student;
}
```

The second case is achieved by this code but bidirectional mapping is not done:

```java
@Entity
class Student {

    @Id
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Address address;
}

@Entity
class Address {

    @Id
    private long id;
}
```

Is there a way to get bidirectional mapping and add an address from the student?

Answer (score 2):

In `Student` you have `@OneToMany Address`. It means that you're telling Hibernate that one student may have **many** addresses.

So it should be:

```
class Student {
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "student")
    private List<Address> addressList;
}
```

And since the relation between `Address` and `Student` is Many-To-One, then one Address may have only one Student.

```
class Address {
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
    private Student student;
}
```

Considering this, your `save` implementation could be the following:

```
Student student = new Student();
Address address = new Address();

address.setStudent(student);
student.setAddressList(Collections.singletonList(student));

studentRepository.save(student);
//addressRepository.save(address); or use AddressRepository
```

Comment: Why do we need to set student to address and again address the student. Can address be saved using only "student.setAddressList(Collections.singletonList(student))".

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use a collection on the `@OneToMany` side:

```java
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "student")
private List<Address> address;
```

> The second thing that I want is address gets automatically added from the student entity when the address is in the student class.

You can achieve it only using [bytecode enhancement](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#BytecodeEnhancement) (see *Bidirectional association management* section). The `hibernate.enhancer.enableAssociationManagement` option is responsible for that.

> Enable association management feature in runtime bytecode enhancement which automatically synchronizes a bidirectional association when only one side is changed